# how to xlim an sns.kdeplot()

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

When plotting the estimated density function of my data using `sns.kdeplot()`, the algorithm extrapolates outside of the boundaries of the data, meaning that it draws the plot for values smaller than 0 or greater than 1, which is particularly annoying when dealing with probabilities. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.random(100)
sns.kdeplot(data)
```

[image]

How to fix that so that the actual plot remains within [0,1] in the x-direction without simply calling `plt.xlim((0,1))`?

Comment: A KDE is defined over the complete range from minus to plus infinity. You cannot restrict it. But, yes, you can use `xlim` to simply not show it outside the range you want to show.

Comment: I see. That's sad but thanks :)